# How do I feed ruby code into rails console and irb from terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In terminal, I want to do something like:

```
rails c << 'puts User.count'
irb << 'puts "Hello World!!"'
```

And get results like following:

```
1278 # for rails c
Hello World # for irb
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Not `<<` - you want `<<<` (so-called "here string"). e.g. `irb <<< 'puts "Hello World!!"'` does what you want.

Comment: @Amadan Maybe I misunderstood, but it looks like he is looking for `eval`, please correct me.

Comment: @ray: No, he wants to "feed ruby code into rails console and irb _from terminal_". Not run `irb` and then type code; but to use one command in shell to run certain code inside `irb`. My comment solves it for bash; Зелёный gives a rails-specific solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`rails runner`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner):

`bin/rails runner "puts User.count"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eval method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Binding.html#method-i-eval)

which evaluates the ruby expression in the string.

For example in your case both in rails console or irb or for [pry](https://rubygems.org/gems/pry) lovers, you can 
do the following

`eval "puts User.count"`           *#your User model count*

`eval 'puts "Hello World!!"'`      *#Hello World*